# redirect from class to gsp page

Tags: java, grails, redirect

I use grails and in service I have class in which before throw an exception it have to redirect to gsp page.

Is there anyone who know how to redirect from class to gsp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, [redirect](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Redirects) is designed to be used at the controllers, not services. Services should contain only the logic of your business, not the routing. Routing is the role of controllers. Moreover, if you throw an exception and then redirect, who will take the exception?

I think the better way is catching the exception thrown by the service at controller level, then do the redirecting.

You can view more abour redirect command [here](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Redirects).

Comment: +1 on this one, redirects should be handled in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`redirect(uri:'foo')`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html), which will redirect to `foo.gsp`.

Update: you should not redirect from service. Services must be completely unaware of the web nature of the application. So, at most, redirection can depend on some return value by a service.

Comment: @Bella how it did not work? What happened? this is the proper way to do it, so it's not the problem - the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: If your in a service you don't get the standard controler methods so redirect won't work.

Comment: @Bella - forward. But investigate _why_ it doesn't work. Are you trying it from a service, rather than controller?

Comment: Bezho I have tried write redirect in service..Before I have used redirect in controller, but now i need to redirect from service..